# Displaying an array with multiple groupings in a select box

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to display data from an array in a select box that has 2 grouping levels, see the screenshot below:

[image: Displayed results]

However I can't find a way to group by both the software and the the type, so that in this example the 'Test' and 'Test2' are displayed after each other under the same headings.

My code is below:

HTML:

```
<select size=20>
  <optgroup *ngFor="let item of items" label="{{item.software | uppercase}}">
   <option disabled class="pl-1">{{item.type | uppercase}}</option>
   <option class="pl-4">{{item.name | titlecase}}</option>
  </optgroup>                    
</select>
```

TypeScript:

```
getItems() {
  this.helper.getItems((data: Array<Item>) => {
    this.items = data;
    this.items.forEach((item: Item) => {
      item.software = 'SoftwareA';
      item.type = 'TypeA';
    });
  });
}
```

Is there anyway this can be done?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Example Data:

```
items = [
 {
   groupKey: 'SoftwareA', data: [
    { type: 'test1', name: 'A' },
    { type: 'test1', name: 'B' },
    { type: 'test2', name: 'C' },
    { type: 'test2', name: 'D' },
    { type: 'test3', name: 'E' },
   ]
 },
]
```

Desired Result:

[image: DesiredResult]

Comment: can ou share with us the data  ?

Comment: @malbarmawi how would you like me to share it with you? it is only made up data

Comment: @malbarmawi I have added some example data above as requested in the same format as your answer below, as I want to show the type as a heading(which I know I can't use another optgroup tag) and then any names that have that type below it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use two ngFor one from the group and other fro option elements  , so as example the data can look like this

```
items = [

    {
      groupKey: 'SoftwareA', data: [
        { type: 'test1' },
        { type: 'test2' },
        { type: 'test3' },
      ]
    },

    {
      groupKey: 'SoftwareB', data: [
        { type: 'test6' },
        { type: 'test7' },
        { type: 'test8' },
      ]
    },

  ]
```

I found the structure above is easier to work with on the template

*template*

```
<select size=20>
  <optgroup *ngFor="let item of items" label="{{item.groupKey | uppercase}}">
   <option *ngFor="let optionData of item.data" class="pl-4">
    {{optionData.type | titlecase}}
   </option>
  </optgroup>                    
</select>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eu4wnz)

**Updated**

becuase we can't have more than one leve we can mange to have a disabled option before spisific otpion as group and set the disable to true so it 's can't be seklected

```
  items = [

    {
      groupKey: 'SoftwareA', data: [

        { type: 'test1' ,  groupKey:true },
        { type: 'test1', name:'A' },
        { type: 'test2' ,  groupKey:true },
        { type: 'test2', name:'B' },
        { type: 'test2', name:'C' },
        { type: 'test3' ,  groupKey:true },
        { type: 'test3', name:'D' },
        { type: 'test3', name:'E' },
      ]
    },


  ]
```

*template*

```
<select size=20>
  <optgroup *ngFor="let item of items" label="{{item.groupKey | uppercase}}">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let optionData of item.data">
   <option *ngIf=" optionData.groupKey;else dataOptionElem"  class="header" [disabled]="true">
     {{optionData.type | titlecase}} 
   </option>
   <ng-template #dataOptionElem>
     <option  class="pl-4">{{optionData.name}}</option>
   </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
  </optgroup>                    
</select>
```

*style*

```
option.pl-4 {
    padding-left: 0.8rem;
    display: block;
}

.header { 
  font-weight: bold;
  color : #000;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f5pvso)

Comment: how do I then display the level below the type? as I will have multiple items below the type as well

Comment: you can show the name of the type like this {{optionData.type | titlecase}} - {{optionData.name}} we can't use optgroup  inside optgroup 

Comment: that is not what I need as I want it be grouped. I have been able to do it in PHP, I was hoping I could do the same with Angular, but it appears I can't then

Comment: that is exactly what I'm after, would you be able to share the code, as that link only shows the result

Comment: I have update the answers  , you need to check the new data structure , hope this will solve your problem 